# Quantum SVM Algorithm Error on import

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, qiskit

I am experimenting with some Qiskit ACQUA AI algorithms which require the following import statement:

```
from datasets import *
```

However, `import` statement is throwing an error:

ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last) in
from datasets import * 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datasets'

I am unable to determine the package that this import is from. Clearly, Qiskit ACQUA installation doesn't have to all required packages for the algorithm code to run. I asked the question at the IBM QE forum but the traffic on it is very low. I have not had the answer from anyone yet.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: I got some answers from another forum and I would like to share here. It turned out that the datasets library was a custom wrapper for the sklearn library. So it wasn't a library installed. To get around this, I navigated to the source and launched jupyter notebook, and that's when it worked. If I figure out a way to install all required librariries, I will be happy to share. Thanks!

Comment: When you are satisfied that you have the correct answer you are welcome to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

@DrHamed : you could have done this.

```
from sklearn import datasets
```

A lot of datasets are available in that import. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html